# Ignoring Null input value when using a parameter with postgres

Tags: postgresql, null

Given this simple table [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8a4477a308321baa1a8d7f3b283c271f)

```
 CREATE TABLE tbl (
  tbl_id             serial PRIMARY KEY,
  column_a       text NOT NULL,
  isactive bool NOT NULL
);
```

```
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (1, 'a', true)
, (2, 'b', true)
, (3, 'c', false);
```

I'm seeing a user using this case statement to suppress a parameter

```
SELECT
tbl_id,
column_a,
isactive
FROM tbl
WHERE CASE WHEN $1 IS NOT NULL THEN isactive = $1 ELSE 1=1 end AND
CASE WHEN $2 IS NOT NULL THEN column_a = $2 ELSE 1=1 end
```

I'm going to suggest that they use this syntax

```
SELECT
tbl_id,
column_a,
isactive
FROM tbl
WHERE ($1 IS NULL OR isactive = $1) and 
($2 IS NULL OR column_a = $2)
```

I think these are equivalent (and probably easier to read). Would you do anything different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion is certainly better and no less efficient than the `CASE` statement.

But `OR` is usually a problem in `WHERE` conditions, because it makes it difficult for PostgreSQL to use indexes to speed up the query.

Better solutions are:

- add the `WHERE` condition to the query only when the parameter `IS NOT NULL`
- write the query as a `UNION`:

  ```
    SELECT tbl_id, column_a, isactive
    FROM tbl
    WHERE isactive = $1 AND column_a = $2
  UNION ALL
    SELECT tbl_id, column_a, isactive
    FROM tbl
    WHERE isactive = $1 AND $2 IS NULL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT tbl_id, column_a, isactive
    FROM tbl
    WHERE $1 IS NULL AND column_a = $2
  UNION ALL
    SELECT tbl_id, column_a, isactive
    FROM tbl
    WHERE $1 IS NULL AND $2 IS NULL;
  ```

  That looks longer and more complicated, but it can use indexes on `isactive` and `column_a`.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it